# Is there any way to post on users behalf, and make it look like an actual post?

Tags: facebook

We need to post a message from the user that looks like an actual status update, without anything giving away that is was made trough an app, no extra images or hyperlinks. We also want to "tag" a page in the post.

Is there any way this is possible without having the user to make the post themselves?

Comment: Ugh. Being for a charity organisation does not make it sound more attractive. In fact, a charity should be grateful to show an extra hyperlink.

Comment: So are you sure this is not possible?

Comment: Well to answer your point alexinblue, the reason we want it to look legit is because it's about becoming a "facebook parent" for orphans in Africa and thus raise awareness, and to achive some kind of virality, we want the post to look like a "family relation post" i.e [Your name] has acknowledged [Orphan page] as his daughter. And this would drive people to the page. And of course everything is communicated to visually and with text what they are about to share.

Answer (score 0):

Publishing something via an App and making it look like the user posted it is not possible, users should always be able to block the app (and with that, the postings of the app). Also keep in mind that the "message" field always has to be user generated, so you are not allowed to use auto-generated content for publishing. After all, posting via an app only leaves a very small footprint, it just writes "via xxxxx" (App Name). The only serious way to post something is via the JavaScript SDK feed dialog anyway:

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

About tagging a page in a post, i am not sure. some months ago it was not possible.

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Search for "Comma-separated list of Facebook IDs of people tagged in this Post" - i guess you can still only tag Users, but you can just try with a Page ID.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for taking your time to answer mate. I totally see the problem in what I'm trying to do. As far as i understand from your answer you can indeed remove the app thumbnail and url, if the only thing that gives it away is the via [app name] that is fine. And regarding the user generated content, I assume it is okay to have pre filled text and then the user can change it however they want.

Comment: well, you could just use a white app thumbnail...about prefilled content: yeah, as long as the user can change it before you post it, it should be alright. just keep in mind that you cannot prefill the message field in the javascript dialog (which is, as i said, the only serious way as it leaves full control to the user).